# Sed remove all content in line after \t

Tags: sed, awk

I have o/p like

```
19599 user  20   0  120m  32m 4260 S 14.0  5.3   3:21.13 app.out  \t Wed Jun  8 09:31:06 UTC 2011
19599 user  20   0  120m  32m 4260 S 14.0  5.4   3:21.61 app.out  \t Wed Jun  8 09:31:12 UTC 2011
19599 user  20   0  121m  32m 4260 S 12.0  5.4   3:22.31 app.out  \t Wed Jun  8 09:31:17 UTC 2011
```

I want to remove all character starting from `\t` in the line. 
How can I do that with `sed`?

I tried with `awk -F t '{print $1}'`
but it removing t from app.out .

I want o/p like

```
19599 user  20   0  120m  32m 4260 S 14.0  5.3   3:21.13 app.out
19599 user  20   0  120m  32m 4260 S 14.0  5.4   3:21.61 app.out
19599 user  20   0  121m  32m 4260 S 12.0  5.4   3:22.31 app.out
```

If I wrote the `awk` like this:

```
 awk -F t '{print $1"t"}'
```

it works fine, but it is only a work around. How can I remove all character starting from `\t` in the line till end of line?

Comment: what do you want to leave in the line? I mean show an example it is not so easy to find \t here)

Comment: Is the `\t` actually a tab character or the sequence backslash and 't'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the output contains the two characters backslash and 't', then you use:

```
sed 's/ *\\t.*//'
```

This removes the blanks leading up to the two characters, the backslash and the 't', plus everything after them.

If the output contains a tab character, then you need to replace the '`\\t`' with an actual tab character.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want the first field in a tab-delimited text. You might try one of:

```
cut -d $'\t' -f 1
awk -F '\t' '{print $1}'
sed $'s/\t.*//'
```

The `$''` syntax is used in bash (and ksh and zsh I believe) to more easily allow for embedding escape sequences in strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" } 1 == 1 {print $1}' file.name
```

Comment: sorry . It is not working I am getting  \t Wed Jun  8 09:30:55 UTC 2011
19599 user  20   0  121m  32m 4260 S  8.0  5.4   3:20.54 app.out                                                                                                               \t Wed Jun  8 09:31:01 UTC 2011

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe it through:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\t.*/\1/'
```

Comment: I am getting 

 \t Wed Jun  8 09:30:55 UTC 2011
19599 user  20   0  121m  32m 4260 S  8.0  5.4   3:20.54 app.out                                                                                                               \t Wed Jun  8 09:31:01 UTC 2011
19599 user  20   0  120m  32m 4260 S 14.0  5.3   3:21.13 app.out                                                                                                               \t Wed Jun  8 09:31:06 UTC 2011